# How to fix HttpErrorMiddleware in scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to so horizontal crawling using Scrapy. Using xpath, I am getting the link of each listing in a real-estate site, as well as the next-page link.

However, when I run my spider I keep getting this error:

"scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware"

Thanks for the help

```
class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'manual'
    allowed_domains = ['web']
    start_urls = ('https://www.nyhabitat.com/new-york- 
    apartment/roommate-share',)  

    def parse (self, response):

        next_selector = response.xpath ('//*[@id="pagination- 
        container"]/ul/li[8]/a/@href')                                   
        for url in next_selector.extract_first():
            yield Request (response.urljoin(url))

        item_selector = response.xpath('//a[contains (@class, 
        "slider-item-link")]//@href')

        for url in item_selector.extract():
            yield Request(response.urljoin(url))

    def parse_item (self, response):
        l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)
        l.add_xpath('price','// 
                   [@id="availability"]/div/div[1]/b/text()',
                   MapCompose(lambda i: i.replace(',', ''), float), 
                    re='[,.0-9]+')
```

Outcome:

```
'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
```

Comment: That's not an error - it's a middleware that tracks http response errors lol. In other words it's perfectly fine!